# iPhone and iPad end of scrolling

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, scroll, infinite

I'm making some jQuery cross-browser gallery with infinite scroll i works great but on iPhone (i suppose also on iPad) instead equal values i have some disproportion values don't match

```
($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())
```

i just want to reach the end of scrolling on that , after that i could invoke AJAX script, also have to keep in mind that values changing after two fingers wipe zoom.

Comment: This should probably be `>=` instead of `==` to catch UIs that push past and bounce back...   like the iPhone?

Answer (score 5):

You need to account for the [60px URL text field on iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW1). Try this:

```
($(window).scrollTop() + 60 == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
        var  scrolltrigger = 0.90;

        if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {

            //Your AJAX CALL HERE
        }
    });
```