# Is there any way to load data while scrolling in jquery for Iphone (mobile websites)

Tags: jquery, iphone, scroll, loaddata

Is there any way to load data while scrolling in jquery for Iphone (mobile websites).
This example works in Safari, Chrome but not in the iPhone:
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dnspinger/

Thanks

Comment: looks like the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6782148/844726  -- you need to add the 60px url field to the `$(window).scrollTop()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way - the best to do it is initiating an AJAX request to a server side page  to retrieve more data from the database.

The website you have mentioned is doing just that however on a device you will need to take the URL box into consideration I believe this is 60px?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(window).scrollTop() + 60 == ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        doFunction();
    }
});

doFunction() {
    $.post('getPosts.php?action=loadmore&endId=' + $('.element:last').attr('id'));

    function(data) {
        if (data != '') {
            $(".element:last").after(data);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example of how you could do this?